# Replacing get variables with slashes

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to get rid of the id's in url bar by make every thing more simple can anyone tell me how to make something like this /math/calculus/limits_topic/vidname

Comment: Url rewrite is your best friend here

Comment: Yes. Every major web framework can. Next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Below .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Pass get method variable to URL then explode it

```
$variables = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

for example :

```
actual url : http://example.com/math.php?calculus=1&limits_topic=1&vidname=1
rewrite url : http://example.com/math/1/1/1
```